# datastax odbc connector crash while test connection

Tags: cassandra, odbc

Hey i'm trying to connect to a cassandra 3.3.0 (localhost, port9042) with the Datastax ODBC 64 bit connector. I followed the instructions on Datastax website but when i try to test the connection the application crash's. Does anybody knows a solution or approach?

Comment: could you post exception details?

Comment: only this " A problem caused this programm to stop interacting with Windows".